# the command ./vendor/bin/sail up didn't work in a laravel project

Tags: laravel, windows, docker

I'm new to laravel and docker I need to use it but when I run the command " ./vendor/bin/sail up " an error displayed
/bin/bash: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\management-app\vendor\bin/../laravel/sail/bin/sail: No such file or directory
I don't understand Where does the problem come from, can anyone have any idea, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this command from WSL2 instead of Windows. You can install any Linux distro, for example, [Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6) and run this command from there.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but I can't access my project folder from ubuntu because it is in windows. this command " cd C:/xampp/htdocs/Laravel/management-app " didn't work for me

Comment: @FatimaTahiri You can try Linux path cd /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/Laravel/management-app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#how-do-i-use-a-windows-file-with-a-linux-app- Or you can install your project inside WSL, it will work faster. You will be able access project files in IDE from Windows anyway.

Comment: I found another solution to that problem without using ubuntu, add "bash" to the beginning of the command like this " bash ./vendor/bin/sail up "